# Font not working on server but fine on local

Tags: fonts

Recently I've uploaded my website using WebDAV to a server. I've found that the free web font that I used is not working but I've correctly written @font-face. I also uploaded the same website onto a different server using FTP and everything worked perfectly. The web font is in OTF format. It also works on my local computer. Any idea where the problem is?

Comment: What does the browser say?

Comment: it dosent say anything the font just switches to default (times new romans i think)

Comment: If you are using Chrome, look at the Network tab in the dev tools to see if there was a problem downloading the font.

Comment: using firefox as my browser